# Problems in Complexity Theory

Tags: complexity-theory

I'm studying Complexity Theory. Many times i found written that in complexity theory every problem come in pair, that is a **search** version and **verification** version.
But why this happens ? What establish this ?

Comment: It's hard to guess what exactly you are referring to. Perhaps you could add a few examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you refer to, but there is a basic translation between *function problems* and *decision problems*. In a function problem, we are given an input $x$ and our goal is to compute a function $f(x)$. In a decision problem, we are given an input $x$ and our goal is to determine whether $x$ belongs to some set $S$.

Given a function problem $f$, we can define an associated decision problem in which the input is a pair $(x,y)$, and the goal is to determine whether $y = f(x)$ (i.e., whether $(x,y)$ belongs to the set $\{(x,f(x))\}$.)

In the other way, any decision problem is a function problem whose output is True or False.

Comment: So, any computation problem reduces to a function problem ? And the decision problem is inextricably linked to its respective function problem ?

Comment: Not exactly. Implementing Windows isn't a function problem, for example. But in complexity theory we are mostly interested in function problems, and particularly in the special case of decision problems.

Comment: But, when we talk about P,NP,NP-complete we are considering only DECISION problems ?

Comment: Yes, these are all classes of decision problems. Sometimes we're interested in optimization problems, which we convert to decision problems in order to relate their complexity to these complexity classes.

Comment: So, the basis problem is the function or the decision ? It's possible to convert every problems to a decision problem ? I ask this because im trying to understand P,NP and NP-Hard problems, and it have many info but im not able to clearly understand

Comment: All of these are classes of decision problems.

Answer (score 2):

Every time somebody sets you some homework – "Find the answer to this question" – you hand in your answers saying, "I think the answer is this. Am I right?"